# I'm hoping to sort the items returned in the following query by the order they're entered into the IN() function

Tags: mysql

### I'm hoping to sort the items returned in the following query by the order they're entered into the IN() function.

```
SELECT t1.product_id
     , SUM(t1.quantity)
  FROM tb_invoice_detail t1
     , tb_products t2
 WHERE t1.del_date > DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)
    AND t1.del_f = '1'
    and  t1.product_id = t2.id 
    AND IFNULL(t2.price_discount, t2.price) BETWEEN 0 AND 100
    and t2.rate >= 0
 GROUP 
    BY t1.product_id
 ORDER
```

### BY SUM(t1.quantity) DESC;

Result:

```
product_id, SUM(t1.quantity)
100320  8
100004  7
100210  5
100226  5
100321  4
100418  3
100002  2
100000  2
100001  2
100474  2
100268  2
```

When I get list data using product_id

```
SELECT 
id,
name,
thumbnail,
description,
price,
IFNULL(price_discount, price) AS price_discount,
rate,
number_total,
number_current,
(CASE
    WHEN number_current = 0 THEN 2
    WHEN (ROUND(number_current / number_total * 100) < 20) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS state
FROM
tb_products
WHERE
id IN (100320 , 100004,
    100210,
    100226,
    100321,
    100418,
    100002,
    100000,
    100001,
    100474,
    100268)
```

=>

```
SELECT 
id,
name,
thumbnail,
description,
price,
IFNULL(price_discount, price) AS price_discount,
rate,
number_total,
number_current,
(CASE
    WHEN number_current = 0 THEN 2
    WHEN (ROUND(number_current / number_total * 100) < 20) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS state
FROM
tb_products
WHERE
id IN (100320 , 100004,
    100210,
    100226,
    100321,
    100418,
    100002,
    100000,
    100001,
    100474,
    100268)
```

Comment: Hi- See FIELD().

Comment: Beyond that, your question is rather obscure. Perhaps see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query